# How does one group and collect string-type array-items by any string-item's first 3 characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, grouping, reduce

Provided is an array of words where some words most likely do have their first 3 characters in common (consider case insensitive) ... similar to this word list example ...

```
['Bob', 'Bobby', 'Robert', 'Robby']
```

Since `'Bob'` and `'Bobby'` as well as `'Robert'` and `'Robby'` do have in common `'Bob'` respectively `'Rob'`, I'm looking for an approach which will return an array of two grouped word arrays which for the former example was ...

```
[['Bob', 'Bobby'], ['Robert', 'Robby']]
```

How would such an approach look like?

Comment: What is "similar beginnings" supposed to mean? 1 letter? 2 letters? Over half their letters in common?

Comment: Added clarification.  In this case they share the first 3 letters, bob and rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect names into an object with their beginnings as keys (see [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)), and then get the values of this object (see [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values))

```js
function getArraysByNameFirstThreeChars(names) {  
  // declare the object for collecting similarely beginning names
  const resultObject = {};

  // iterate through the names
  for (const name of names) {
    // get 3 first characters of the name
    const strStart = name.substring(0, name.length >= 3 ? 3 : name.length);
    // if there's already a member in the object
    // for this beginning, push the name to it
    if (resultObject[strStart]) {
      resultObject[strStart].push(name);
    } else {
      // otherwise, create a member in the collection object
      // for this name-beginning, comprising of an array
      // with only current name in it
      resultObject[strStart] = [name];
    }
  }
  return Object.values(resultObject);
}

const names = ['Bob', 'Bobby', 'Robert', 'Robby'];
const whatYouWant = getArraysByNameFirstThreeChars(names);

console.log(whatYouWant);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me!  I'll give this a try now.

Comment: Ok.  So first I'll say thank you again.  

This code is missing one thing.  In `substring` it should be `(0, 3)` so that it begins at the first  letter and ends at the third.  Just `(3)` matched but it pulled Bobby and Robby into the same group and orphaned the other two to their own.

Cool thing is, I was able to figure that out.  I'm learning!  Woohoo!

In this example it worked.  What if I had an Array of Objects and I was doing this with a Value inside the Objects?

Let's say its: `[{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Bobby'}, {name: 'Robert'}, {name: 'Robby'}]`

Comment: you're right with the `substring(0, 3)` syntax, I've edited the answer. Regarding your question about objects - it would be exactly the same, but instead of `name.substring(0, 3);` it would be name.name.substring(0, 3);`. You can also rename the loop variable to something more appropriate than 'name' in this case :) P.S.: do accept the edit I've made to the question, the syntax there is incorrect right now

Comment: You're a rock star!  The actual code I'm working with was in another post that got flagged [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65411754/javascript-how-do-i-group-an-array-by-their-partial-common-unique-identifier) and it's the last thing I have left to do on a 6 month long project for a client.  Now I'm one step closer.  Now to average those results!  All this to get 3 numbers...

Comment: @KevinHandy ... the above approach does not recognize / handle the case(s) of word duplicates and words shorter than 3 characters. At some point one also might run very likely into case sensitivity issues.

Comment: @PeterSeliger there was no request regarding handling duplicates or handling case sensitivity, but you're 100% right about names less than 3 letters. Edited my answer

Comment: @grreeenn ... if the code was provided as executable snippet my upvote was already there.

Comment: @PeterSeliger another time, maybe :) as a frequent consumer of SO answers I don't see any difference, then so be it. Rewrote it as function though, it's better that way.

Answer (score 0):

As so often [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#How_reduce_works) proves itself to be the *Swiss army knife*.

A single configurable reducer function does the job. An additionally to be provided start value, the collector object, does feature the `groups` object which later holds all the collected and grouped word lists. A `length` property can be configured as well. It represents the character count of any word's start sequence by which all words are going to be grouped and collected. Omitting this property defaults internally to a number value of `3`.

The reducer exclusively collects unique words. Thus duplicates within the to be processed array will be filtered.

For an end result which is expected to be an array of array(s) of word(s) one just needs to pass the return value's `groups` key to `Object.values` ...

```js
// Added clarification.
// In this case they share the first 3 letters, bob and rob.

function groupAndCollectWordsBySimilarStartSequences(collector, word) {
  const { groups, length = 3 } = collector;
  const index = collector.index || (collector.index = {});

  // process non duplicate words of minimum length only.
  if ((word.length >= length) && !(word in index)) {

    const groupKey = word.slice(0, length).toLowerCase();
    const groupList = groups[groupKey] || (groups[groupKey] = []);

    groupList.push(word);
    index[word] = word;
  }
  return collector;
}

console.log(
  'grouped index :',

  ['Bob', 'Bobby', 'Robert', 'Robby', 'Bob', 'Robby'].reduce(
    groupAndCollectWordsBySimilarStartSequences, {
      groups: {},
      length: 2,
    }
  ).groups
);
console.log(
  'array of arrays :',

  Object.values(['Bob', 'Bobby', 'Robert', 'Robby'].reduce(
    groupAndCollectWordsBySimilarStartSequences, {
      groups: {},
      length: 2,
    }
  ).groups)
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'grouped index :',

  ['Bob', 'Bobby', 'Robert', 'Robby', 'Bob', 'Robby'].reduce(
    groupAndCollectWordsBySimilarStartSequences, {
      groups: {},
    }
  ).groups
);
console.log(
  'array of arrays :',

  Object.values(['Bob', 'Bobby', 'Robert', 'Robby'].reduce(
    groupAndCollectWordsBySimilarStartSequences, {
      groups: {},
    }
  ).groups)
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'grouped index :',

  ['Bob', 'Bobby', 'Robert', 'Robby', 'Bob', 'Robby'].reduce(
    groupAndCollectWordsBySimilarStartSequences, {
      groups: {},
      length: 4,
    }
  ).groups
);
console.log(
  'array of arrays :',

  Object.values(['Bob', 'Bobby', 'Robert', 'Robby'].reduce(
    groupAndCollectWordsBySimilarStartSequences, {
      groups: {},
      length: 4,
    }
  ).groups)
);
console.log('\n');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me!  I'll give this a try now.